# angles between vectors in a high-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I am constructing a set $S$ of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$, where $|S|\leq N$.

Can I *arbitrarily* and *independently* assign values to the angles between all pairs of vectors in the set? It is impossible when $|S| > N$, but I am not sure if it is possible for $|S|\leq N$.

In other words, if I have an arbitrary symmetric matrix $M \in \mathbb R^{|S|\times |S|}$ (each element is in the range $[0, \pi]$), can I always find a set $S$ of $N$ dimensional vectors whose pair-wise angle matrix is $M$, when  $|S|\leq N$?

Comment: The angle between $u$ and $v$ can't exceed the sum of the angle between $u$ and $w$ and the angle between $w$ and $v$, can it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these angles are constrained. As a simple counterexample, take $N=|S|=3$ with $M$ being $\pi$ on the off-diagonal and zero otherwise. This would require the three vectors to be mutually anti-parallel, which is plainly impossible.

To sharpen this one typically studies not the angles but the dot products $R_{ij}=\cos M_{ij} = \vec{v}_i\cdot \vec{v}_j$ between the vectors in set $S$. To simplify the resulting discussion, I'll further assume from here that these vectors in $S$ all have unit length. Then one has the following inequality:
$$\|v_1+v_2+v_3\|^2 = 3+2(v_1\cdot v_2+v_2\cdot v_3+v_1\cdot v_3)\geq 0$$
That is, the quantity $v_1\cdot v_2+v_2\cdot v_3+v_1\cdot v_3$ is at least $-2/3$. This amounts to a (nonlinear) constraint on the angles generated by these inner products, and in particular forbids all three dot products from being $-1$, i.e., the counterexample indicated above. Moreover, it is not the only such constraint: we can replace $v_1+v_2+v_3$ with arbitrary coefficients to generate an infinitude of such constraints.

To manage these inequalities more systematically, we switch from the matrix $M$ of angles to the matrix $R$ of dot products. Such a matrix is known as a Gram matrix, and it has a tidy representation: If we let $V\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times |S|}$ be a matrix whose column vectors are the (unit) vectors in $S$, then the definition of matrix multiplication immediately yields $R=V^\top V$.

From here we can prove a key property of such a Gram matrix $R$: For any vector $u\in \mathbb{R}^{|S|}$, we have $$u^\top R u = \| Vu\|^2\geq 0.$$ That is, $R$ is a positive semi-definite matrix (typically denoted as $R\succeq $ 0). To connect this with our above work, note that $u=(1,1,1)^\top$ yields $Vu=v_1+v_2+v_3$ and thus recovers the prior inequality. So the infinite family of linear inequalities indicated above is equivalent to $R\succeq 0$.  The family of such Gram matrices is a convex body known as the $n$-elliptope, with each linear inequality corresponding geometrically to one of its tangent half-spaces.

Moreover, note that the inequality is saturated iff $Vu=\sum_{k=1}^{|S|} v_k u_k=0$. But this amounts to these vectors being linear dependent. If we require that the vectors in $S$ be linearly independent, then the inequality is sharp and $R$ is positive definite ($R\succ 0$). The advantage of making this final change is that we can now appeal to [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion): a real symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if its leading principal minors are all positive. We thereby reduce the problem to a finite set of inequalities, at the cost of these constraints being on *polynomials* of the dot products rather than linear functions as above. (If we relax to positive semi-definite $R$, we can proceed similarly but now we have to check *all* principal minors not just the leading ones.)

This does still leave us with quite a bit of work, and in particular these inequalities are hardly elementary as the dimension increases. However, the case of $N=3$ is tractable. In particular, in this setting the matrix $R$ of dot products will be positive semi-definite so long as $\det R=(\det V)^2$ is nonnegative. This yields the following inequality on the off-diagonal elements $R_{12},R_{13},R_{23}$:
$$ \det R = 1-R_{12}^2-R_{13}^2-R_{23}^2 +2 R_{12}R_{13}R_{23}\geq 0$$
This yields the following picture for the 3-elliptope:

[image]

Note that this looks like a somewhat-inflated tetrahedron. There is a final surprise to be had here, but it is one whose details I will leave to the reader: If we convert this set of possible dot products back into the set of possible angles, what body do we obtain?

Comment: Ah thanks, thinking in terms of Gram matrix is very nice. For any positive semi-definite matrix $R$ of size $|S| \times |S|$ and rank $N$, we can always find $V$ of size $N \times |S|$ that satisfies $R=V^TV$ by performing SVD on R (i.e. $R=USU^T$ where $U$ is an orthonormal matrix then $V=Q\sqrt{S}U^T$ where $Q$ is an arbitrary orthonormal matrix.) So I should have had an additional criterion that $R$ is a positive semi-definite matrix to make the statement in the question true.